# Final Destination History/Lore

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Many stages in the SSB universe are based on the games from which the SSB characters are drawn. But certain stages, including [Final Destination](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Final_Destination_(SSBM)) and [Battlefield](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Battlefield_(SSBM)) appear to have been created specifically for SSB.

For example, the [Battlefield Trophy](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Battlefield_(SSBM)#Trophy_information) explains (emphasis mine):

> Super Smash Bros. Melee borrows settings from many different games to create its stages, **but the Battlefield is an original creation.** While its initial impression may strike some players as a bit ominous, the layout itself is fairly standard, lending it to serious, straightforward matches. Additionally, it's used to pit players against the Fighting Wire Frames.

However, no such confirmation exists for the similarly styled Battlefield stage.

**Is there any history/lore to the Final Destination stage?**

Does it come from a game, or more likely, is it also an original creation made for SSB? The [Final Destination trophy](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Final_Destination_(SSBM)#Trophy_information), unlike the Battlefield trophy, is not particularly informative:

> As time passes on this stage, the level appears to travel through a wormhole from the imaginary Super Smash Bros. Melee world into reality. You move through a cloud-filled sky over a vast mountain range, then into a deep-space vista of dark blues and purples. The scenery is as real as you get in this fantastical world.

Is there any lore or history for Final Destination?

Comment: Why the downvotes? I believe this is about in-game plot and game lore, which I think is on-topic - https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9863/what-defines-a-lore-question

Comment: I'm happy to delete if someone can explain to me why this is off-topic

Comment: Seems like a perfectly valid question to me

Comment: @JonK That's what I thought, and I appreciate the upvote!

Comment: I'm not a voter here, but even though lore questions are on-topic, there are quite a few users who don't like them/do not think they are of value here.

Comment: The question is valid. Downvotes are not used to signify validity, rather they are usually used for low quality questions or questions that serve no real purpose. In the past, people who asked about downvotes usually receive more because...reasons.

Comment: @Vemonus Ahh, I understand

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Gotcha, appreciate the advice, I'll have to be more careful in the future I suppose..

Comment: It seems to me the answer *is* in the trophy description. "Appears to travel through a wormhole from the imaginary Super Smash Bros. Melee world into reality."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Final Destination has no lore behind it besides that it's referred to as [Master Hand's Residence](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Destination_(SSB)). It's his home.

In different iterations of SSB, the background changes between different stages, [changes color](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Final_Destination_(SSB4)) depending on Master Hands health and even changes speed at which it flies through space and time.

People have conjectured that the stage is linked with Master Hand, although no in-game proof has been provided for such theories. Another theory is that FD is the link between the [subspace emissary levels](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Destination_(SSBB)), in which FD is the [final stage.](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Final_Destination_(SSB))

For now, just enjoy the greatest stage in the game and the trippy backgrounds

For the record, a great resource and a highly verified website by the community with all kinds of information about SSB is [Smashpedia](http://supersmashbros.wikia.com/wiki/Smashpedia). I used to use this site ALL the time in college when I played in tournaments.

Comment: Appreciate the response - do you by chance have any links to sources (so I can do some further reading)?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein Done.

Comment: Yeah I use Smashpedia as well, though admittedly only read the Melee entry on Final Destination. But great answer!